# How to check if tag <a> or/and <img> is the children of div on Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

So, let's say I have page like this inside of the `<body>` tag

```
<!-- Tag <a> with <img> inside of it -->
<div class="album_item">
    <a href="http://www.foo.com/img/1"><img src="http://thumbnail.foo.com/img/1.jpg" /></a>
    <a href="http://www.foo.com/img/2"><img src="http://thumbnail.foo.com/img/2.jpg" /></a>
    <a href="http://www.foo.com/img/3"><img src="http://thumbnail.foo.com/img/3.jpg" /></a>
    <a href="http://www.foo.com/img/4"><img src="http://thumbnail.foo.com/img/4.jpg" /></a>

</div>

<!-- Only tag <img> -->
<div class="album_item">
    <img src="http://large.foo.com/img/5.jpg" />
    <img src="http://large.foo.com/img/6.jpg" />
</div>

<!-- Combination Of Both Above -->
<div class="album_item">
    <a href="http://www.foo.com/img/7"><img src="http://thumbnail.foo.com/img/7.jpg" /></a>
    <a href="http://www.foo.com/img/8"><img src="http://thumbnail.foo.com/img/8.jpg" /></a>
    <a href="http://www.foo.com/img/9"><img src="http://thumbnail.foo.com/img/9.jpg" /></a>
    <a href="http://www.foo.com/img/10"><img src="http://thumbnail.foo.com/img/10.jpg" /></a>

    <img src="http://large.foo.com/img/11.jpg" />
    <img src="http://large.foo.com/img/12.jpg" />
</div>
```

And I want to scrap using the code below :

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

my_url = 'http://www.foo-url.com'

uClient = requests.get(my_url)
page_html = uClient.text
uClient.close()

page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

#Identify Each Post Group
containers = page_soup.findAll("div",{"class": "album-item"})

data = []

for container in containers:
    #Store Each Pictures To An Object
    items = container.findAll("a")

    for item in items:
        #Set The Link Location
        link_location = item.attrs['href']
        image_item = item.find("img")

        #Set The Image Location
        img_location = image_item.attrs['src']

        data.append((link_location, img_location))

    #Just Incase Only Image
    imgs = container.findAll("img")

    for img in imgs:
        link_location = "NoLink"
        img_location = img.attrs['src']
        data.append((link_location, img_location))

for link_location, img_location in data:
    print(link_location + " | " + img_location)
```

And On the result, There is a lot of duplicates like this :

```
http://www.foo.com/img/1 | http://thumbnail.foo.com/img/1.jpg
http://www.foo.com/img/2 | http://thumbnail.foo.com/img/2.jpg
http://www.foo.com/img/3 | http://thumbnail.foo.com/img/3.jpg
http://www.foo.com/img/4 | http://thumbnail.foo.com/img/4.jpg

NoLink | http://thumbnail.foo.com/img/1.jpg       #duplicate
NoLink | http://thumbnail.foo.com/img/2.jpg       #duplicate
NoLink | http://thumbnail.foo.com/img/3.jpg       #duplicate
NoLink | http://thumbnail.foo.com/img/4.jpg       #duplicate

NoLink | http://large.foo.com/img/5.jpg
NoLink | http://large.foo.com/img/6.jpg

http://www.foo.com/img/7 | http://thumbnail.foo.com/img/7.jpg
http://www.foo.com/img/8 | http://thumbnail.foo.com/img/8.jpg
http://www.foo.com/img/9 | http://thumbnail.foo.com/img/9.jpg
http://www.foo.com/img/10 | http://thumbnail.foo.com/img/10.jpg

NoLink | http://thumbnail.foo.com/img/7.jpg       #duplicate
NoLink | http://thumbnail.foo.com/img/8.jpg       #duplicate
NoLink | http://thumbnail.foo.com/img/9.jpg       #duplicate
NoLink | http://thumbnail.foo.com/img/10.jpg      #duplicate

NoLink | http://large.foo.com/img/11.jpg
NoLink | http://large.foo.com/img/12.jpg
```

My idea is, to check inside of the `<div class="album_item">`
if all of the children tag `<a>` , then do the `for item in items:`
else if all of the children tag `<img>` , then do the `for img in imgs:`
but then what if there are both of tag ?

And I am not sure how check that tag either
On the first `<div>`
I tried to use `if(container.select("img"))` which should be false,
but the value is true because it detect the tag `<img>` that is inside of tag `<a>`

So, how should I approach this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing you want, is **`tag.find_all(recursive=False)`**.

From the [documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-recursive-argument):

> If you call `mytag.find_all()`, Beautiful Soup will examine all the
>   descendants of `mytag`: its children, its children’s children, and so
>   on. If you only want Beautiful Soup to consider direct children, you
>   can pass in `recursive=False`.

In your code, change this line

```
imgs = container.findAll("img")
```

to

```
imgs = container.findAll("img", recursive=False)
```

Output:

```
http://www.foo.com/img/1 | http://thumbnail.foo.com/img/1.jpg
http://www.foo.com/img/2 | http://thumbnail.foo.com/img/2.jpg
http://www.foo.com/img/3 | http://thumbnail.foo.com/img/3.jpg
http://www.foo.com/img/4 | http://thumbnail.foo.com/img/4.jpg
NoLink | http://large.foo.com/img/5.jpg
NoLink | http://large.foo.com/img/6.jpg
http://www.foo.com/img/7 | http://thumbnail.foo.com/img/7.jpg
http://www.foo.com/img/8 | http://thumbnail.foo.com/img/8.jpg
http://www.foo.com/img/9 | http://thumbnail.foo.com/img/9.jpg
http://www.foo.com/img/10 | http://thumbnail.foo.com/img/10.jpg
NoLink | http://large.foo.com/img/11.jpg
NoLink | http://large.foo.com/img/12.jpg
```